# How to secure custom endpoint for rest api in Wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I have several endpoints under `fs/v1`.  I was to require authentication even for `GET` requests.  How is that implemented please?

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('fs/v1', 'posts', [
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'fs_posts',
    ]);
});
```

Comment: Have you read https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `permission_callback` parameter and set it to whatever authentication you want to apply.

So, if you want to make it accessible to a user having `manage_options` capability, your code should be something like this-

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('fs/v1', 'posts', [
        'methods'             => 'GET',
        'callback'            => 'fs_posts',
        'permission_callback' => function( $request ) {
            return current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
        }
    ]);
});
```

If it's for any logged-in users, for example, use this-

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function(){
    register_rest_route('fs/v1', 'posts', [
        'methods'             => 'GET',
        'callback'            => 'fs_posts',
        'permission_callback' => function( $request ) {
            return is_user_logged_in();
        }
    ]);
});
```